# How to set minimum number of instances to split in Random Forest in Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka

How do we set the minimum number of instances to split on parameter (corresponding "min_samples_split" and "min_samples_leaf" parameter in sickit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in Weka Random forest in Java ? I looked at the documentation here   http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html but could not find the solution .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

from the [RandomForest](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) link you provided, i think it is `-M`, basically the minimum number of nodes at leaf.

> -M    Set minimum number of instances per leaf.   (default 1)